# Formulário pai sobrepondo formulário filho C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Windows Forms no Visual Studio e estou com uma dificuldade.

Setei o formulário pai pra IsMdiContainer e ao invés de adicionar Toolbox, fiz um formulário só com botões, acontece que ao clicar no botão e abrir o formulário filho, o formulário pai se sobrepões ao filho.

[image: Formulário pai]

[image: Formulário filho sobreposto]

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmlancar lancar_serv = new frmlancar();

        // Define quem o pai desta janela
        lancar_serv.MdiParent = this;

        // exibe o formulário
        lancar_serv.Show();



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar o [`ShowDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.) ao invés do `Show`.  `ShowDialog` trava o foco para a janela invocada:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmlancar lancar_serv = new frmlancar();

    // Define quem o pai desta janela
    lancar_serv.MdiParent = this;

    // exibe o formulário
    lancar_serv.ShowDialog();
}
```

Se mesmo assim não funcionar, coloque a propriedade `lancar_serv.TopMost = true;` antes da linha do `ShowDialog`.